# how to make an interactive button that creates a semicircle around it when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, geometry

So I want to create a button that would go in the bottom of my screen and create a semicircle around it with more buttons inside when clicked. I've tried adjusting the CSS but Im not able to come up with a solution. Do you guys know a way to do it? I came across this codepen ("https://codepen.io/jet/pen/LwiGu"), which is almost exactly what I want, instead of creating a whole circle around it, it would create a semicircle around the top. I've attached an image for you guys to understand it better.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.menuItem');

for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
  items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
  
  items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
}

document.querySelector('.center').onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); document.querySelector('.circle').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
@import "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css";

body {
  /* Image source: http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/718405 */
  /* Excuse the base64 mess, imgur blocked the hotlinked image and this seemed like the fastest solution */
  background: cornflowerblue url(" data:image/png;base64,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") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

a {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}

.circle,
.ring {
  height: 256px;
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
}

.circle {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ring {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;

  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1) rotate(-270deg);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1) rotate(-270deg);
  -transform: scale(0.1) rotate(-270deg);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.open .ring {
  opacity: 1;
  
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0);
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0);
}

.center {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 80px;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.open .center {
  border-color: #aaaaaa;
}

.menuItem {
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #eeeeee;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="ring">
    <a href="" class="menuItem fa fa-home fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="menuItem fa fa-comment fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="menuItem fa fa-play fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="menuItem fa fa-camera fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="menuItem fa fa-music fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="menuItem fa fa-user fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="menuItem fa fa-trash-o fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="menuItem fa fa-star fa-2x"></a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="center fa fa-th fa-2x"></a>
</div>
```

[menu mockup][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR419.png

Comment: Does this reference help you?

https://codepen.io/jbro/embed/EBOvRd?height=316&theme-id=0&default-tab=result

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your desire correctly, then all you'd have to change is this:

- The `.ring` currently has height&width 256px, change that if you want it bigger/smaller.
- Now re-position the `.ring` so that it is aligned with the bottom of its container. You do that by setting a negative `bottom` of exactly half the `.ring`s `height` (so something like `bottom: -128px;`).
- Now you have to decide how many icons you need on there (there used to be 8 buttons in your source, but now that we clipped it, there is only 4 visible).
- Now, adjust the 2 javascript lines (the ones with `...Math.PI...` in it) to account for

  - (A) the amount of icons you want and
  - (B) the fact that you only want to populate the upper half of the `.ring`

The 2 `Math.PI` lines (which set the position of each individual button, aren't complicated but how you have to change them depends entirely on how big you're making the thing, and how many button you want to place on it - so i cannot really provide an example without knowing that.